# python tkinter: how i can get the IntVar() for radiobutton when they are in groups

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, radio-button

I have the following problem, I need to check which radiobutton is active and get its value, for example...

```
radio1 = Radiobutton(mainframe,text='rbutton1', value=1, variable=1)
radio2 = Radiobutton(mainframe,text='rbutton2', value=2, variable=1)
radio3 = Radiobutton(mainframe,text='rbutton3', value=3, variable=2)
radio4 = Radiobutton(mainframe,text='rbutton4', value=4, variable=2)
```

with this i can select 1 radiobutton in each group but i can't use the get() method to check which one is selected

but when i use this example...

```
var = IntVar()
radio1 = Radiobutton(mainframe,text='rbutton1', value=1, variable=var)
radio2 = Radiobutton(mainframe,text='rbutton2', value=2, variable=var)
radio3 = Radiobutton(mainframe,text='rbutton3', value=3, variable=var)
radio4 = Radiobutton(mainframe,text='rbutton4', value=4, variable=var)
```

i can use the get() method but i can select all buttons at the same time and that is not what i need, every group can only have one selected radiobutton

thank you for your help

Comment: i can't replicate this, when you use the `IntVar` all the widgets are linked to it, only one `RadioButton` linked to the same variable can be active at a time. if you need multiple groups you create multiple `IntVar`'s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a normal integer as the value for the `variable` option. Well, you can, as your code illustrates, but there is no way to get the value back out.

You must provide one of the tkinter variables as the value of the `variable` option. All radiobuttons with the same `variable` will be tied together in a group. If you want two groups, you will need to use two variables. Also, you should initialize the varibles to have one of the allowed values, otherwise your radiobuttons will likely not be in the state that you expect.

```
group1 = IntVar(value=1)
group2 = IntVar(value=3)

radio1 = Radiobutton(mainframe,text='rbutton1', value=1, variable=group1)
radio2 = Radiobutton(mainframe,text='rbutton2', value=2, variable=group1)

radio3 = Radiobutton(mainframe,text='rbutton3', value=3, variable=group2)
radio4 = Radiobutton(mainframe,text='rbutton4', value=4, variable=group2)
```